# Modal Bootstrap abrir conteúdo de outra página

Tags: jquery

Gostaria que ao clicar no botão, abrisse em um modal Bootstrap o conteúdo de outra página. Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnImprimir" title="Clique para imprimir sua carteira" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Imprimir</button>
    <div class="modal drag" id="modalImprimir" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div>
                      <div id="tela">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    <script>
              $("button").on('click',"#btnImprimir", function(){
                alert('aqui');
                  $.post('carteira-imprimir.php', function(retorno){
                         $("#modalImprimir").modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
                         $("#tela").html(retorno);
                  });
              });
    </script>
```

E a página carteira-imprimir.php

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="font-weight: bold"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i> CARTEIRA ESCOLAR</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     Conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

Só que ao clicar, não abre o modal e nem o alert() que coloquei para teste. Como faço para corrigir isso?

Comment: Seu seletor está incorreto. Em vez de `$("button").on(...` deveria ser `$(document).on(...`

Comment: Olá Sam. Perfeito!! Funcionou! Muito obrigado mais uma vez! Se quiser colocar como resposta, eu clico em aceitar como a resposta correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seletor do click está incorreto usando `"button"`, porque o elemento com o id `#btnImprimir` é o próprio botão.

Ou você altera para `$(document)`:

```
$(document).on('click',"#btnImprimir", function(){...
```

Ou usa o próprio elemento no seletor usando a id:

```
$("#btnImprimir").on('click', function(){...
```